# Adding an image to a Section in Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have created a view using MonoTouch.Dialog with a couple of sections. The sections require an image to be added before the other sections, however I am struggling to add the UIImage to the area before the first Section.

How would I go about this? I have highlighted where in the RootElement I would like the Image to go.

```
public void HomeScreen ()
    {
        var root = CreateRoot_HomeScreen ();

        var dv = new DialogViewController (root, true);
        navigation.PushViewController (dv, true);
    }

    RootElement CreateRoot_HomeScreen()
    {
        // Set up the ImageView with the Logo in it
        var logo = UIImage.FromFile("Images/logo.png");

        var imageView = new UIImageView(logo);

        return new RootElement("iEngage"){
            // The Image should go here
            new Section(){

            },
            new Section("")
            {
                new StyledStringElement ("Search", delegate{ Console.Write("Clicked"); })
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the **Headers and Footers** from MonoTouch's **Sample**. Basically each `Section` you add has `HeaderView` property that you can set.

Your `UIImageView` could be assigned to this property which would insert your *logo* in the section.

E.g. (copy/pasted from [DemoHeaderFooters.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/Sample/DemoHeadersFooters.cs))

```
        var section = new Section () { 
            HeaderView = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromFile ("caltemplate.png")),
        };
```

Then you use this section in your code:

```
   return new RootElement("iEngage"){
        section,
        new Section("")
        {
            new StyledStringElement ("Search", delegate{ Console.Write("Clicked"); })
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks poupou. I tried this and I get a distorted image which is stretched/distorted to fit into the width and height of a Section. Can I specify these width and heights somewhere else?

Comment: poupou, I worked out how to change the height by setting the frame property of the UIImageView - thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it, don't hesitate to edit my answer and add this if you think it will help people!

Comment: Macropus - how did you get rid of the stretch in the UIImageView?  This doesn't work for me... name.FooterView = new UIImageView(image) { Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100) }; I still get an image stretched across the whole table's width (although the height gets adjusted to what I specified).

Comment: @OmriGazitt Check out this [Image Resizer for MonoTouch](http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.com/2011/08/monotouch-class-for-resize-maintaining.html)

Comment: @ChuckSavage thanks!  I ended up fixing this myself by wrapping the UIImageView in a UIView, which is a trick that seems to work when the various iOS view subclasses (e.g. UIImageView, UIButton, etc) are getting sized by their parents.