# decrease height of UITableViewController [monotouch if possible]

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Tried below properties but didn't work like I need :

this.TableView.ContentInset 
this.TableView.ContentOffset

Basically, I have image header at the very top of the uitableviewcontroller , so when tableview gets populated , header image is laid over by cells ...plz look at the image

[image]

Eventually, I want to shift cells a little down to leave room for the title image.

---

update :

added this code and somehow worked

```
UIImageView img = new UIImageView (new RectangleF ((this.View.Bounds.Width- 164)/2,0, 164, 44));
img.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/app-name.png");
this.TableView.TableHeaderView(img);
```

[image]

but the image is stretched out

Comment: This fixed it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards

Answer (score 1):

Add your image in table header `tableHeaderView`.

Also, set custom height to the table header - sectionHeaderHeight:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

*Note: these are UITableView class's properties. I am not sure about Monotouch but you might be able to find some similar properties in it.*

---

Please try any of the following:

Refer to this answer and its comments: [Adding an image to a Section in Monotouch.Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424847/adding-an-image-to-a-section-in-monotouch-dialog)

```
HeaderView = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromFile ("imagename.png"))
```

Or refer to this : http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/monotouch-class-for-resize-maintaining.html

---

Try this : [iphone: put uiimage in tableview section header, stretch problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091477/iphone-put-uiimage-in-tableview-section-header-stretch-problem)

Comment: Could you please update your code in question? Its hard to read here. It would also be better if you could add screenshot of that.

Comment: If that's a static image then you could add it in Storyboard or Interface builder or your designer

Comment: You can't add code in comments! Edit your question and add your code there. I am not an expert with Monotouch but I think there might be some size issue with `RectangleF`

Comment: May be try to find how to set the size for `RectangleF`. Also, try to set the image in your designer.

Comment: the image is exactly the same size and location on 3 other views . If you see the first image , it's actually the same one with same dimensions !

Comment: i even set width to 40 instead of 164 but didn't change the size !

Comment: What is your image's size - width x height ?

Comment: width = 164 , height = 44 ...i tried this UIImageView img = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (0,0, 10, 44));
but didn't work ...size doesn't get changed

Comment: Sorry man , didn't work ...and also i'm not using Monotouch.Dialog so i can try that code ...any other thoughts ??

Comment: I have added another link in my answer

Comment: hey man , sorry to sound dumb ! i tried the solution in the link you posted , and i hope i translated the code right but it didn't have any effect ...I'm doing that in the ViewDidLoad event ...any thoughts !

Comment: Ok , it's fixed now ..i used trick here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards   ...... thanks a lot for your time